# short `csvgrep` equivalent as bash drop-in function

Tags: csv

Question: Nice "drop-in" replacements to grep some lines of [csv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) files containing some keywords in some column.

Requirement: support more complex csv files - that have double quotes, newlines.

Usecase: "csvkit" is awesome, but it might be too much to just grep few lines.

There is very nice [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io) for working with [csv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) files, that includes [csvgrep](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.1/scripts/csvgrep.html?highlight=csvgrep). But sometimes, environment for which we are writing script does not have csvkit isntalled and installing/compiling all might be overkill for just greping few lines of [csv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file.

Answer (score 0):

- -1: require python2
- +1: python2 is more commonon than csvkit

bash drop-in function:

```
function csvgrep(){
grep_criteria="$1"
matchcolumn="$2"
python2 -c "import csv, sys
rows = list(csv.reader(sys.stdin))
writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
writer.writerow(rows[0])
for row in rows[1:]:
  if row[${matchcolumn}] == '${grep_criteria}':
    writer.writerow(row)"
}
```

Usage:

```
csvgrep 'valueInLastColumn' '-1' < in.csv > out.csv
```